# Android: Socket client not receiving message from server

Tags: android, sockets

I have read many posts with same issue, As we are reading lines i.e. `BufferedReader.readLine()` so we have to send `"\n"` from the server so that android client take it as a new line. But my problem is I cannot change my server code as it is communicating with desktop application as well and it is already coded. Is there any way to read the message from the server without adding `"\n"`?

`Android client class`

```
public class TCPClient {

private String serverMessage;


public static String SERVERIP = "192.168.0.1"; // controllers IP address
public static final int SERVERPORT = 10001;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;
private PrintWriter out = null;
private BufferedReader in = null;


public TCPClient(final OnMessageReceived listener) 
{
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
  * Sends the message entered by client to the server
  * @param message text entered by client
  **/
public void sendMessage(String message)
{
    if (out != null && !out.checkError())
    {
        System.out.println("message: "+ message);
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient()
{
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        if(!MainActivity.STATIC_IP.equals(""))
        {
            SERVERIP = MainActivity.STATIC_IP;
        }

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Connecting...");

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);


        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Sent.");
            Log.e("TCP SI Client", "SI: Done.");
            Log.e("Out Message",out.toString());

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


            while (mRun)
            {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {

                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Log.e("TCP SI Error", "SI: Error", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TCP SI Error", "SI: Error", e);
    }

}

    public interface OnMessageReceived {
       public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```

How other client `(Python)` is getting the message.

```
data = self.sock.recv(1024)
```

What server send are commands `@alarm:On#, @alarm:Off#` 4 commands per second without any line break at the end.

Comment: How does the other client do it? The protocol must already be defined. Just implement it. Nobody here can tell you about your own protocol. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: The other client is in python and it will get the data using self.sock.recv(1024)

Comment: If that's all there is to it, which I doubt, why can't you just do the same thing in this case?

Comment: The code you've now posted should exit the loop if `readLine()` returns null, but it's all irrelevant if the server isn't sending line terminators, and until you tell us what the server does send, or what the Python client code actually looks like.

Comment: And now that you've done that you need to answer my question as to why you can't do the same thing in Java. Even if it's more complex than a single read, which it surely must be to work at all, there is nothing stopping you from transcribing that code into Java, and no reason why you should be fixating on `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: Because I don't know how to do that in java. Any help from you would be appreciated.

Comment: Come off it. The Javadoc exists. You found `readLine()`. Keep looking.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I get the message just like python did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @EJP your clue help me sort out the `issue`. 
Here is the working `code`.

```
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));     
    int charsRead = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (mRun)
    {
         charsRead = in.read(buffer);
         serverMessage = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
         if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
             Log.i("Message from Server", serverMessage.toString());
         }
     }
}catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thx for adding the solution here. It helped me to solve same situation I had trouble in.

Answer (score -2):

You should work yourself through the Java Tutorial on [Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) to get a better understanding on how to use them.

Since your Question suggest you have no way of knowing when the Server message ends, I'd use a buffered stream and count the readable chars, then read those chars into an array and convert those into a String.

Comment: use [available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) depending on the subclass, of course.